# Getting "undefined" in my function in findMyCampsites()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

This was the coding challenge:

> Qualified challenge requirements:
> Write a function `findMyCampsites()`.
> Given a campgrounds array, a type of view as a string, and the party size as a number, return an
> array with campsite numbers for the matching campsites. That is, your function should return
> results that match the following three criteria:
>
> a. Currently available campsites (`isReserved === false`) 
> b. With the view that matches the input string (such as `ocean` or `forest`) 
> c. That can host the party size of the input number, or greater 
> If no sites are available, return the string `Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party`

This is the sample Array given:

```
let campgrounds = [ 
    { number: 1, view: "ocean", partySize: 8, isReserved: false }, 
    { number: 5, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: false }, 
    { number: 12, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: true }, 
    { number: 18, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: false }, 
    { number: 23, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: true }, 
];
```

This is the example return given:

```
//example input/output 

findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 4); //-> [1, 5] 
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 8); //-> [1] 
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 4); //-> [18] 
findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 6); //-> 'Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party'
```

This is my code:

```
function findMyCampsites(campgrounds, views, size){
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < campgrounds[i].view.length; j++){
      for (let p = 0; p < campgrounds[i].partySize.length; p++){
        for (let n = 0; n < campgrounds[i].number.length; n++){
          if (campgrounds[i].view[j] === views && campgrounds[i].partySize[p] <= size && campgrounds[i].isReserved === false){
            return array.push(campgrounds[i].number[n]) + ", ";
          }else {
            return "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting `undefined` in as my return value. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `return array.push(campgrounds[i].number[n]) + ", ";` this line is strange, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Anyway, read something about `filter()`, that should be a much cleaner way of fixing this

Comment: If things match then you are returning always the string `1, `, I don't think that's right. But anyway, what if any of those arrays (`campgrounds` itself or any `view`, `partySize` or `number`) are empty? Then the innermost loop body never runs, there is no `return` at all, so it's `undefined`.

Comment: What's wrong is about everything. You only want one iteration, you go once through the campgrounds. Check for the current campground if it is not reserved, has enough place and fits the type. if so, yield the campground and check the next one

Comment: The ", " was a mistake, I'm noticing. I was thinking I needed to add that between the numbers, like in the return value they showed, But I'm realizing that was incorrect

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to steer clear of basic `for` loops and try using high-level idiomatic JS array methods which provide a much clearer conceptual framework for approaching array algorithms. In this case, we're filtering to find the campsites, then mapping those campsites to their ids--two loops, no nesting. If you are going to use bare loops, return only at the very end rather than after the first check.

Also, code like `campgrounds[i].number.length` and `campgrounds[i].partySize.length` doesn't make sense because these properties aren't arrays, they're plain numbers. To debug this, you'd normally print or inspect the property and see that it's undefined.

```js
const campgrounds = [ { number: 1, view: "ocean", partySize: 8, isReserved: false, }, { number: 5, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: false, }, { number: 12, view: "ocean", partySize: 4, isReserved: true, }, { number: 18, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: false, }, { number: 23, view: "forest", partySize: 4, isReserved: true, }, ];

const findMyCampsites = (campgrounds, view, partySize) => {
  const res = campgrounds.
    filter(e =>
      !e.isReserved &&
      e.view === view &&
      e.partySize >= partySize
    )
    .map(e => e.number);
  return res.length
    ? res
    : "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";
};

console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 4)); //-> [1, 5]
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "ocean", 8)); //-> [1]
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 4)); //-> [18]
console.log(findMyCampsites(campgrounds, "forest", 6)); //-> 'Sorry, no campsites
```

Here's the same thing without the array methods for pedagogical purposes only:

```js
const findMyCampsites = (campgrounds, view, partySize) => {
  const res = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    const e = campgrounds[i];

    if (
      !e.isReserved &&
      e.view === view &&
      e.partySize >= partySize
    ) {
      res.push(e.number);
    }
  }

  return res.length
    ? res
    : "Sorry, no campsites with that view are available to host your party";
};
```

The above code wouldn't be too bad if it used a `for (const e of campgrounds)` loop. The counters are ugly and error-prone, which the original code proves. When you use high-level iteration, you'll get a clear error trying to iterate non-iterables rather than a silent failure and there's no `.length` property to have to reason about.

Also, functions generally should only return a single type. Notwithstanding the task's requirements, it's better to return an empty array rather than a magical string `"Sorry..."` to indicate failure, which can lead to all kinds of maintainability issues (potential bug: assuming the return's `.length === 0` means no campsites were found--the caller would have to do `typeof result === "string"` or compare it against the magic string all over again--not fun), mixing presentation and logic and creating typing nightmares in a codebase (`number[] | string` is a nasty signature to have to work with).

Comment: really helpful thank you. the (return res.length) I haven't seen that syntax yet in my early prep work stage, but everything worked at expected. Thank you.

Comment: I see you used that ternary expression at that end, which i hadn't considered, pretty new to those expressions as well.

Comment: The ternary `return res.length ? res : "error message"` is mostly cosmetic, just shorthand for an `if`/`else` and uses `res.length` as a boolean to check whether `res` is empty or not. If it's non-empty (i.e. `.length > 0`) then return `res`. Otherwise, `.length === 0`, return the default string.

Comment: oh, that's good to know. Thank you. sometimes these little interactions feel a 100 times more helpful then the lesson plans